# LINQ - Count and sum duplicates in List<Tuple<int, double>>

Tags: c#, linq

Since I haven't used LINQ much, the following is a hard task for me:

Having a list like `List<Tuple<int, double>>`, I want to receive a list containing the amount (count) of duplicates of Item(1) and the corresponding sum of Item(2). The list should be ordered descending by the count of duplicates.

How would a LINQ look like to get the result?

Comment: Can you make our life easier, and provide some test inputs and outputs we can copy-paste?

Comment: So you want to *group* according to item1, *where* the size of the group is larger than one, *select* the  *sum* of item2 in each group, and *orderby* the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So. Given some inputs (I'm using ValueTuple rather than Tuple, as there's zero reason to use the old Tuple these days):

```
var inputs = new List<(int key, double value)>()
{
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 5),
    (3, 6),
    (3, 7),
};
```

We first want to group the inputs by the key, to give us a collection of key -> elements with that key. We've got two options here: `GroupBy` and `ToLookup`. We'll use `ToLookup`, as that makes the `Count()` operation we'll do in a minute cheaper:

```
var result = inputs
    .ToLookup(x => x.key);
```

This gives us three groups:

```
1 -> (1, 1), (1, 2)
2 -> (2, 3)
3 -> (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7)
```

Then we want to remove all of the groups where the number of items in the group is 1 or less:

```
var result = inputs
    .ToLookup(x => x.key)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Which gives us:

```
1 -> (1, 1), (1, 2)
3 -> (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7)
```

Then we want to take each group, and turn it `(number of elements in the group, sum of values in the group)`. Mapping is done with `Select`.

To find the sum of the values, we've got a couple of options:

1. We can use `Select` to get the `value` member of each element, then use `Sum()` on the result: `x.Select(tuple => tuple.value).Sum()`
2. We can use `Aggregate` with a starting value of its accumulator of `0`, and add the `value` member to it: `x.Aggregate(0.0, (s, x) => s + x.value)`

```
var result = inputs
    .ToLookup(x => x.key)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => (count: x.Count(), sum: x.Select(tuple => tuple.value).Sum()));
```

This gives us:

```
(count: 2, sum: 3),
(count: 3, sum: 38)
```

Finally we want to order by the `count` member:

```
var result = inputs
    .ToLookup(x => x.key)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => (count: x.Count(), sum: x.Select(tuple => tuple.value).Sum()))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.count);
```

This gives us:

```
(count: 3, sum: 38),
(count: 2, sum: 3)
```

[See it on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWACgKAGAAgppQG5GX2aAdABkAlngCOPBowBuAQyisxABxwYAzqwC8rPDADurUeowAeABRiMrANYwAnmlaEIOYABsYree5wwAlAB85v6MAN6MrFGs5jRONP5okdGxTlSJyVHmVE4AzBkM0TG5TgCsBUXmJaxIFSnVAOwFAL5SsgqssOo47tY6KmrqmawCACoQQhAQNjjK5gjagawIAnb2oYXRAgDqABYwsPOLywIAwq54GCGsSwnDAgDKMJ5gVwtaS+aQ+Fgn5z8hJzdAC2IBOTxeVwws08x2hyk8Ah8fn8jxwwJC/g2RQEAHkoIQDgAhewAERg6jAMDwhDEAHMjh8Tt9LtituNjFd/G0GF0ehgBKT0XNuUA==).

Answer (score 4):

@JonasH explained the concept to achieve the result.

With these steps:

1. Group by `Item1`.
2. Perform count for grouped key and sum for total `Item2`.
3. Find duplicate `Item1` with `Count` is greater than 1.
4. Order by `Count` descending.

```cs
var result = input.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
            .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Item = x.Key,
                        Count = x.Count(),
                        Sum = x.Sum(y => y.Item2)
                    })
            .Where(x => x.Count > 1)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Count)
            .ToList();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E8kpg3)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy using basic LINQ methods such as GroupBy and Select, as below

```
var random = new Random();
var testData = Enumerable.Range(0, random.Next(10, 25))
    .Select(x => (random.Next(2), random.NextDouble()))
    .ToList();

var result = testData
    .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count(), Sum = x.Sum(y => y.Item2), })
    .Where(x => x.Count > 1)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .ToArray();
```

Below is the result of running above code.

Sample data
[image]

Result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

```cs
var list = new List<Tuple<int,double>>();

var yourResult =  list
      .GroupBy(tuple => tuple.Item1)
      .Select(group => new {
        Count = group.Count(),
        Sum = group.Sum(tuple => tuple.Item2)
      })
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
      .ToArray();
```

Comment: This misses the requirement "I want to receive a List containing the amount (count) of **duplicates** of Item(1)"